# Form input values to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization

**The Issue**

I am trying to convert form inputs to a json object but having difficulty trying to achieve this, below is a snippet of the HTML which I have and the JSON which I'm trying to get.

```js
{
    "2019-01-23": [
        {
            id: 1,
            period: 'am'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            period: 'pm'
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
<select name="dates[2019-01-23][0][id]">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="dates[2019-01-23][0][period]">
    <option selected>am</option>
    <option>pm</option>
</select>

<select name="dates[2019-01-23][1][id]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="dates[2019-01-23][1][period]">
    <option>am</option>
    <option selected>pm</option>
</select>
```

**What I've tried**

```
var inputs = $(':input').serializeArray();
var json = [];
$.each(inputs, function(key, input) {
    var names = input.name.split(/\[(.*?)\]/);
    var data = [];

    data[names[1]] = [];
    data[names[1]][names[3]] = { id: null, period: null };
    if(names[5] == 'id') {
        data[names[1]][names[3]].id = input.value;
    }
    if(names[5] == 'period') {
        data[names[1]][names[3]].period = input.value;
    }

    json.push(data);
});
```

But this doesn't quite achieve what I'm after (multiple of the same date) and I'm getting a bit lost now, I'm sure there must be a way of doing this a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is more appropriate for your case than `split`.

Furthermore, since `json` is object literal, it should be initialised with empty object (`{}`), not array.

`push` is not quite appropriate for your case. It's better to use direct assignment instead.

So the code might look like this:

```js
var inputs = $(':input').serializeArray();
var json = {};
$.each(inputs, function(key, input) {
    var keys = input.name.match(/([^\[\]]+)/g).slice(1);
    var date = keys[0], i = keys[1], id = keys[2];
    if (!json[date]) json[date] = [];
    if (!json[date][i]) json[date][i] = {};
    json[date][i][id] = input.value;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="dates[2019-01-23][0][id]">
    <option value="1" selected>1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="dates[2019-01-23][0][period]">
    <option selected>am</option>
    <option>pm</option>
</select>

<select name="dates[2019-01-23][1][id]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="dates[2019-01-23][1][period]">
    <option>am</option>
    <option selected>pm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This almost works, however it's returning the date within the square brackets, e.g. `[2019-01-23]` instead of `2019-01-23`. Any ideas?

Comment: @Karl Sorry, I forgot that `match()` with `g` flag returns full matches, not captured groups. Fixed.